# Fill in-between entries in an ID vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

Looking for a quick-and-easy solution to a problem which I have only been able to solve inelegantly, by looping. I have an ID vector which looks something like this:

```
id<-c(NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,NA,2,2,2,NA,3,NA,3,3,3)
```

The NA's that fall in-between a sequence of a single number (`id[6], id[14]`) need to be replaced by that number. However, the NA's that don't meet this condition (those between sequences of two *different* numbers) need to be left alone (i.e., `id[1],id[2],id[8],id[12]`). The target vector is therefore:

```
id.target<-c(NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,2,2,2,NA,3,3,3,3,3)
```

This is not difficult to do by looping through each value, but I am looking to do this to many very long vectors, and was hoping for a neater solution. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seem to work. The idea is to use `zoo::na.locf` in order to fill the `NA`s correctly and then insert `NA`s when they are between different numbers

```
id.target <- zoo::na.locf(id, na.rm = FALSE)
id.target[(c(diff(id.target), 1L) > 0L) & is.na(id)] <- NA
id.target
## [1] NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA  2  2  2 NA  3  3  3  3  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I had never seen na.locf() before. Just implemented this, but out of curiosity: could one write the first line in simple `base R'`?

Comment: You could do something like `c(NA, id[!is.na(id)])[cumsum(!is.na(id)) + 1]`

Comment: @daanoo : In addition to David's comment, also, as `approxfun(seq_along(id), id, "constant")(seq_along(id))` which is similar to how `zoo::na.locf` is actually implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option

```
 d1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(seq_along(id), id), function(x) {
     i1 <- min(x):max(x)
     data.frame(val= unique(id[x]), i1)}))
 id[seq_along(id) %in% d1$i1 ] <- d1$val
 id
 #[1] NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA  2  2  2 NA  3  3  3  3  3
```

Comment: Thanks. This was more or less how I had solved it, but I was looking to avoid looping through. Maybe for no good reason, really, other than to see what was possible

Comment: @daanoo  No problem.  If you have showed your code, I wouldn't have spend time on that route.